# log4php + PHP 7 - catching and logging Throwable

Tags: php, exception, php-7, php-7.1, log4php

I am having trouble logging a "TypeError" with log4php. I suspect this is because I recently upgraded from php 5.5 to 7.1.

Usually, my syntax looks like this:

```
<?

use Logger;

class MyClass
{
    /** @var Logger */
    private $logger;

    function __construct(array $configParams)
    {
        Logger::configure('logger.xml');
        $this->logger = Logger::getLogger(__CLASS__);
    }

    public function dostuff()
    {
        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $this->logger->error("ERROR CAUGHT", $ex);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The above syntax will print lots of info to the log file, including a stack trace. However after reading the latest php7 docs, I believe I'm meant to handle the \Throwable interface, in order to catch both errors and exceptions (which is great). So I replace the above catch with the following:

```
catch (\Throwable $ex)
```

This still prints stack-trace information for my exceptions, but when a "TypeError" is caught, nothing gets printed to the log file.

I assume that this is due to log4php not knowing how to log errors. How can I log errors using log4php in a universal way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `$ex->getMessage()` for error() method your code should be

```
 catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $this->logger->error("ERROR CAUGHT", $ex->getMessage());
        }
```

For logging trace you should use trace

```
 catch (Exception $ex)
            {
                $this->logger->trace("ERROR CAUGHT", $ex);
            }
```

Comment: But then no stack-trace :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this

```
$this->logger->error("ERROR CAUGHT", $ex);
```

with

```
$this->logger->error("ERROR CAUGHT : " . $ex->getMessage());
```

[log4php](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/quickstart.html)'s documentation says that error method has just one parameter.

Comment: it's an optional parameter, see (https://logging.apache.org/log4php/apidocs/class-Logger.html#_error)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out why the original file name and line number was not logged by log4php when an exception is thrown. It turned out that my custom exception_handler class was only logging the exception message (by doing `$exception->getMessage()`), which does not contain the file name nor the line number. All I to do is concatenate that info: `$exception->getFile()` and `$exception->getLine()`:

```
public function exception_handler ($exception) {
        $logger = Logger9::create();
        $logger->info($exception->getMessage()." ".$exception->getFile()." ".$exception->getLine());
}
```

Don't forget to register the custom handler:

```
@set_exception_handler(array($this, 'exception_handler'));
```